# Master .tex with all packages and config

Tags: overleaf

I would like to have a .tex file that stores every config I use i.e. packages, set up of this packages etc

Actual example:

I have this [Overleaf Project](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/examples/simple-stylish-box-design/stzmmcshxdng), that configures type of boxes I want to use in my following projects. I don't want to paste all config again in every new project so... this request arises.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Are you asking "how do I input one tex file into another?" Because the answer is `\input{file.tex}`

Comment: @Seamus if I create a file.tex with every package etc I want and when I create a project I use \input{file.tex}, every config, package would be set up?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/637541/
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/278817/
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/419425/

Comment: If the question was really about overleaf in particular, does [this](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Can_I_create_my_own_LaTeX_templates%3F) help?